# noUiSlider(Using the steps API) + wNumb - wNumb formating doesnt work for the first tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, nouislider

I'm stuck.. I want to create multiple range sliders with noUiSlider. Each slider has to handle between to values (min=2600000, max=8500000,). I format the number using a wNumb, but formatting only works on the second tooltip (1st is ignoring).

See my current code here:

**HTML**

```
<div id="steps-slider"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var stepsSlider = document.getElementById('steps-slider');
var input0 = document.getElementById('input-with-keypress-0');
var input1 = document.getElementById('input-with-keypress-1');
var inputs = [input0, input1];

var moneyFormat = wNumb({
    decimals: 0,
    thousand: ' ',
});

noUiSlider.create(stepsSlider, {
  start: [2650000, 8500000],
  connect: true,
  tooltips: [true, moneyFormat],
  range: {
      'min': 2650000,
      'max': 8500000
});
```

[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaQtQ.jpg)
[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJgUk.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `true` for the first tooltip, instead of a formatter. That'll provide a tooltip with the default slider formatting. To use your formatter for both tooltips, use `tooltips: [moneyFormat, moneyFormat]`.